# Type syntax - What's the meaning of this syntax in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript; I don't understand the meaning of this syntax; can anybody explain it to me?

```
type Type1<K> = K extends string ? { [P in K]: string } : never;
```

If type K extend string, than Type1 will be a document of array of strings? Something like:

```
{"x": ["a", "b", "c"],
 "z": ["d", "e", "f"]
//etc
}
Or
{"x": "a",
    "z": "b"
//etc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let first look at `{ [P in K]: string }` this is a mapped type. If `K` is a union of string literal types (ex: `'a' | 'b'`) the result of this type will be an object type with those names as keys and of `string` type (so `{ a: string, b: string }`). This is actually equivalent to the predefined `Record` type.

The `K extends string ? ... : never`  is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). This means that if `K` is union type, each member of the union will be taken and put through the mapped type. So for example:

```
type ex = Type1<'a' | 'b'> => 
    ('a' extends string ? { [P in 'a']: string } : never) | ('b' extends string ? { [P in 'b']: string } : never) =>
    ({ [P in 'a']: string }) | ({ [P in 'b']: string }) => 
    { a: string } | { b: string }
```